# Spring Boot MockMVC Unit Testing | application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm testing an endpoint and the response content-type is "application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1", when I expect it to be "application/xml".  Can you see where I may have misconfigured the produces aspect?  I added it to the @RequestMapping for the function and received the same, unexpected, result.

### Feature Under Test

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sitemaps",
    consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public class SitemapQueryControllerImpl implements SitemapQueryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> GetSitemapIndex() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("<Hello>", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

### Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SitemapQueryControllerImpl.class, secure = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationTestContext.class})
public class SitemapQueryController_Spec {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() { }


    @Test
    public void GetSitemapIndex_Successul() throws Exception {

        String expect = "<Hello>";
        mockMvc.perform(get("/sitemaps/index.xml")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE))
                    .andExpect(content().xml(expect));
}
```

Comment: It might be happen since you are missing `@ResponseBody` annotation after your `@Controller` annotation, there is a subtle difference between `@Controller` and `@RestController` (= `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default charset is UTF-8, **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** is who manages the charSet. You can override by implementing the bean and setting charSet to null.

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    jsonConverter.setDefaultCharset(null);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use `application/xml` as your produces/accepts configuration (as is done through the method you use), it uses the default charset, which for compatibility reasons is set to the ISO charset you're getting returned. I've encountered the same issue today and yesterday, and the solution is to explicitly pass `application/xml;charset=utf-8` as contentType and accept headers, and check that you get `application/xml;charset=utf-8` as the contentType of the returned content. The easiest way to do this is to construct it using the `new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.getSubType(), StandardCharSets.UTF_8)` constructor to create a new MediaType for `application/xml;charset=UTF-8` that you can then use in your test requests.